# É errado usar as facades na view do laravel para apresentar elementos ao usuário master?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, view

Gostaria de saber se é problemático fazer esse tipo de validação nas views do `Laravel`.

*Exemplo:* Apenas um usuário master pode excluir certo registro, então eu apresento o botão excluir apenas se o usuário for master (logicamente validando as exclusões no `Controller`).

*Exemplificando em código:*

```
@if(Auth::user()->administrator)
    <a title="Excluir" href="/users/delete/{{$user->id}}">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
@endif
```

É correto fazer dessa forma ou é preferível criar novas views para um usuário administrador caso ele tenha poucos privilégios a mais que um usuário comum?

Comment: Eu faço assim. Pra mim é certo e está funcionando.

Comment: Também faço rsrs, mas gostaria de saber várias opiniões

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade não é `helpers` que está utilizando é o `facade` da classe [Autenticação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication). Bom o cenário é resumido, eu faria para melhorar uma [`View`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views) que contem esse *código* e chamaria com [`@include`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#including-sub-views) na [`View`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views) que vai utilizar esse trecho de *código*.

> `botao.blade.php`

```
@if(Auth::user()->administrator)
    <a title="Excluir" href="/users/delete/{{$user->id}}">
         <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
@endif
```

> na [`View`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views)

```
@include('botao')
```

pelo menos assim não ia ficar repetindo muito código e não está errado nesse pequeno exemplo, a quantidade excessiva disso sim pode ser tratado como problema, ou a falta de padrão nisso também pode se tornar ruim para quem vai dar manutenção.

<sup>**Referencias:**</sup>

- [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication)
- [Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views)
- [Including Sub-Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#including-sub-views)

Comment: Obrigado, vou alterar na pergunta.